# Does $A=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}: x>0\}$ have any isolated points?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}: x>0\}$ and $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x>0\}$. I think that it is easy to understand and to prove that the set $B$ does not contain any isolated points, but can we say the same about set $A$? Are the point's in $A$ all isolated?

Comment: Are you considering $A$ as a subset of the reals? What can you say about a neighborhood of a positive rational, say $1?$ Is there such a neighborhood that contains no rational number other than $1?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x<y \in A$ then $\frac{x+y}{2} \in A$ and $x<\frac{x+y}{2}<y$.
Since $A$ contains at least two points, no point in $A$ can be an isolated point.

Answer (score 0):

Between any rational and real number is another rational number (you should prove this if you haven't already). Hence, for any open ball of radius $r$ around a point $x$ of $A$, you can choose another rational point $x'\in A$ that lies between $x$ and $x+r$. Hence for each $x\in A$ there exists no neighborhood of $x$ containing no other points of $A$, so $A$ contains no isolated points.